# ios UTI for address / map locations

Tags: ios, xcode, uti

'ello folks.

I have noticed that there seems to be some sort of UTI that registers apps as being able to open a location. An example of that would be the address of events in the Facebook app, or the address of events in the Meetup app when you click "directions".

In either case by clicking it you get very limited options, usually "open in Apple Maps", "open in Google Maps", meaning the system seems to recognise as an "address". So the question without much further ado is, uh, how.

I have already taken a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1 but can't seem to find something that seems so address specific :c

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way an application can register to provide simple maps display of a location, but you can register the ability of your app to provide directions.

This is done through the capabilities panel of your Xcode project -

[image: Directions capabilities]

The process is described in the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html), including the UTI that you need to support, which is the 'special value' `com.apple.maps.directionsrequest`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, Maps gives 3 UTI's :-

1. "**public.plain-text**"
2. "**public.url**"
3. "**public.vcard**"